# Does ehcache restore order while retrieval

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, ehcache

Say I have a `List<List<someObject>> someList {{A,B},{C,D}}`.  `'A'` being the first element and `'B'` being the second element in the first list element and so on.
Using `ehcache`, I stored the `List<List<someObject>> someList` in the `ehcache` with some key.

During retrieval, does `ehcache` guarantee the order in which the list is retrieved i.e `{{B,A},{D,C}}` is possible?? or it will always be {{A,B},{C,D}}.

Note: The order of the outside list is maintained...but the order of the inner lists is reversed

`ehcache` internal implementation doc any??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're asking about a property of the `List`, and a decent `List` implementation will maintain the order of the elements even after serialization. That's not a problem for ehcache or any other third party library.

Note that ehcache usually stores the cache data in RAM. In case it lacks enough RAM space, it may flush the data into disk (previous configuration).

So, looks like you're retrieving the list and reversing it. Note that you're working with the exact same object reference, so even if you don't *store it back* into ehcache, the state of the `List` is still affected.

More info:

- [Ehcache. Storage Options.](http://ehcache.org/documentation/2.4/user-guide/storage-options)

Comment: @ThrinathDosapati I'm searching about it and doesn't seem to add anything about it. Are you sure you're not reversing the list somewhere else in your code?

Comment: @ThrinathDosapati I wonder if you don't apply `Collections#reverse(yourList)` somewhere in your code, because probably ehcache is storing the data in RAM, and if you reverse it in any part of the code, it will be reversed in ehcache as well.

Comment: Yes I do reverse my collection after retrieval. I was under the impression that cache is stored in disk as I mentioned "<diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir"/>" in my ehcache.xml. Is it still stored in RAM?? Can you correct me here if I am wrong..

Comment: My assumption itself is wrong. That solved my prob..Thanks anyway